# how to register new view in compoenent

Tags: php, joomla, components, new-operator, ads

I'm using Joomla ads_manager. My question is how can I register new view in the component? I ad a folder put the same code as other view for example rules that is only text (the rules component works) and it gave me

500 - View class not found [class, file]: adsmanagerViewregister, C:\xampp\htdocs\trademac-php\trunk\components\com_adsmanager\views\register\view.html.php

error

What is the problem, I've registered the view in the router of the component. that is working it is redirecting to the register bu the error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to change the code , just adding the folder is not enough.

- class **X**View**Yy** extends JView

where **X** Is ur component name and **Yy** is ur view name (note the first caps letter in the view name)

you also need to have a file called default.php inside the viewfolder

```
VIEW-Name
  tmpl/default.php
  view.html.php
```